# how i can select element with double class with querySelector()

Tags: javascript, ajax, dom

i'm having problem when i want to select element using querySelector

```
<ul class="xoxo blogroll">
    </ul>
```

how i can select that `ul` element, in my code i'm use like this

```
var list = document.body.querySelector('ul[class="oxo blogroll"]');
    alert(list.innerHTML);
```

but the return is `null`,i'm sure element ul with `class xoxo blogroll` is defined...
thanks for your answer..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
document.body.querySelector("ul.xoxo.blogroll")
```

And that is it...

Comment: You were faster, but my answer is correct (without typos :-) )

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
document.body.querySelector('ul.xoxo.blogroll')
```

Comment: upvoting because 1 minute should not be the difference between success and failure

Comment: @MarcelFalliere: Sometimes I am the fastest gun in the west, sometimes I'm not. :)